# Passing multiple arguments to sAjaxSource in jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

i have jquery datatable
i need to pass 2 arguments with this code does not works
perhaps does not call the procedure

```
    var params = {
        "name": "ProgressivoRichiesta", "value": $("input[name='<%=txtTargaResponsabile.UniqueID%>']").val(),
        "name": "sDataIncidente", "value": $("input[name='<%=txtDataSinistro.UniqueID%>']").val()
    }

   $('#listReceivedMail').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "dataType": 'json',
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "CinfoService.svc/ProcedureName",
            "data": params,
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

To pass the parameters the way you're currently doing it requires this change:

```
var model = { ProgressivoRichiesta: $("input[name='<%=txtTargaResponsabile.UniqueID%>']").val(),
              sDataIncidente: $("input[name='<%=txtDataSinistro.UniqueID%>']").val()
};

$('#listReceivedMail').DataTable({
            destroy: true,
            "dataType": 'json',
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "CinfoService.svc/ProcedureName",
            "data": JSON.stringify(model),
```

But to pass them using the API, you need to do this:

```
$('#listReceivedMail').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
                 "url": "CinfoService.svc/ProcedureName",
                 "data": function ( d ) {
                     return $.extend( {}, d, {
                        ProgressivoRichiesta: $("input[name='<%=txtTargaResponsabile.UniqueID%>']").val(),
                        sDataIncidente: $("input[name='<%=txtDataSinistro.UniqueID%>']").val()
                     });
                 }
            },
```